# Getting selected option value inside span tag

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get the selected option value which resides insides a span tag.

```
<span id ="resolutionSpan">

    <select name="resolution" id="resolution">
    <option value="0" selected >0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>     
    </select>

</span>
```

I have tried

```
var e = document.getElementById("resolution");
console.log( e.options[e.selectedIndex].text);
```

But that returns a null value. Do i need to iterate the span first?

Due to project limitations, i cant use jquery. Need ur comments in javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get selected value of dropdownlist using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript)

Comment: @MelanciaUK Please check that i have mentioned about span tag, consider it before downvoting.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript

Comment: Voting is anonymous.

Comment: @Satheesh the span tag is irrelevant, you are selecting the select by ID.

Comment: And to get the selected value of a dropdownlist, it doesn't really matter what kind of element is wrapping it. You go for it. Check the duplicated question.

Comment: The issue was the same span tagname was used by other spans too. I renamed it and everything works fine now. Thanks everyone for the answers. In my scenario, i should go with value not with text.

Answer (score 1):

Get the `.options`, then `.selectedIndex`, then `.text`.  Like this:

```js
var selected = document.getElementById('resolution').options[document.getElementById('resolution').selectedIndex].text

alert(selected);
```

```html
<span id ="resolutionSpan">

    <select name="resolution" id="resolution">
    <option value="0" selected >0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>     
    </select>

</span>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I believe .text selects the label.

If you want the value of the selected item use .value.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9wxqmLL1/

```
var e = document.getElementById("resolution");
console.log( e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is actually very close, just change .text to .value:

```
var e = document.getElementById("resolution");
console.log( e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);
```

unless you wanted to get the actual content of the option (which in this case is the same value but still)

```
var e = document.getElementById("resolution");
console.log( e.options[e.selectedIndex].innerHTML);
```